# Difference in behavior using ng-include with webpack locally vs production

Tags: angularjs, webpack, require, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using webpack with angular, I have an HTML file with ng-include:

```
<ng-include src="stringUrl"  ng-if="true"></ng-include>
```

In the controller I'm setting the stringUrl:

```
this.$scope.stringUrl = 'app/some-view.html';
```

This is working fine when running locally with "webpack-dev-server", but when building using webpack the main.bundle.js file does not contain some-view.html.

So I tried to change the controller to:

```
this.$scope.stringUrl = require('app/some-view.html');
```

So now when building using webpack, some-view.html is inside main.bundle.js. But scope.stringUrl gets the HTML content and ng-include fails (because its expecting a url).

If I remove ng-include and instead just put:

```
<div>{{stringUrl}}</div>
```

it will work in production, but will not work locally, because stringUrl will not have the content of the HTML.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Israel

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to work with `ng-include` tag in development & production, using $templateCache.

First need to inject `$templateCache` (`$templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService`) so we can use it in the controller / directive.

Then putting in `$templateCache` the file content (using `require`):

```
    this.$scope.stringUrl = $templateCache.put("some-view.html", require("app/some-view.html"));
```

In the view file, the tag `ng-include` should refer to the key (with ' ' encapsulating URL):

```
<ng-include src="'some-view.html'"></ng-include>
```

Now everything work as expected.